# Yii2: Validation in form with two instances of same model

Tags: php, validation, activerecord, yii, yii2

I have a model Booking with the fields shipping_address and billing_address, both of the model Address.
I now want to print them to the same form which basically works pretty well, the problem is the fields of both models have the same IDs. For example the field "zip" in the shipping_address has the id "zip" and the "zip" in billing_address also has "zip" as its id.

If I now fill out the form, it validates both of the fields at the same time while only one of them is actually true.

[image][image]

I've already changed the names of the fields to Shippping_Address['zip'] and Billing_Address['zip'] therefore the controller is able to recognize both models.

Here's how the fields are printed:

```
<?= $form->field($billing_address, 'address_line_1')->textInput(['maxlength' => 45, 'name'=> 'Billing_Address[address_line1]']); ?>
<?= $form->field($billing_address, 'address_line_2')->textInput(['maxlength' => 45, 'name'=> 'Billing_Address[address_line2]']) ?>
<?= $form->field($billing_address, 'zip')->textInput(['maxlength' => 11, 'name'=> 'Billing_Address[zip]']) ?>
<?= $form->field($billing_address, 'city')->textInput(['maxlength' => 45, 'name'=> 'Billing_Address[city]']) ?>
<?= $form->field($billing_address, 'country')->textInput(['maxlength' => 45, 'name'=> 'Billing_Address[country]']) ?>

<?= $form->field($shipping_address, 'address_line_1')->textInput(['maxlength' => 45, 'name'=> 'Shipping_Address[address_line1]']); ?>
<?= $form->field($shipping_address, 'address_line_2')->textInput(['maxlength' => 45, 'name'=> 'Shipping_Address[address_line2]']) ?>
<?= $form->field($shipping_address, 'zip')->textInput(['maxlength' => 11, 'name'=> 'Shipping_Address[zip]']) ?>
<?= $form->field($shipping_address, 'city')->textInput(['maxlength' => 45, 'name'=> 'Shipping_Address[city]']) ?>
<?= $form->field($shipping_address, 'country')->textInput(['maxlength' => 45, 'name'=> 'Shipping_Address[country]']) ?>
```

Edit: After implementing the answer of tony:

```
<?= $form->field(
            $shipping_address,
            'address_line_1',
            [
                'selectors' => [
                    'input' => '#shipping-address_line_1',
                    'container' => '.shipping-address_line_1'
                ],
                'options' =>
                    ['class' => 'shipping-address_line_1']
            ])->textInput([
                'maxlength' => 45,
                'name'=> 'Shipping_Address[address_line1]',
                'id'=>'shipping-address_line_1',
            ]); ?>
```

I also changed the container class because it was the same as the one the other field had. Now the second field (with the code as shown above) is working perfectly. The problem is, the first field (with the code unchanged) is not validating anymore.

How could this be solved?

Comment: try to set *id* attribute explicitly for each zip input

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tony. Which id do you mean? I was talking about the html attribute id. If I change that one, the validation just does nothing anymore.

Comment: can you provide a code that generates this inputs ?

Comment: Added the code in the original question

Comment: Why do you set 'name' and 'id'? Yii is doing this automaticaly (i.e. <?= $form->field($model_variable, 'test')->textInput(); ?> will be <input type="text" id="modelname-test" name="ModelName[test]">. Leave it be, the problem must be in your controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you use one model class for generating two sets of inputs at one page, yii2 generates identical *clientValidation* rules for both of them. To separate validation you need to set *id* attribute for each input that required validation in each of this sets manually. For your zip input field the solution will be next *(edited according to latest comments)*:

```
//Billing
$form->field($billing_address, 'zip', 
[
    'selectors' => [
        'input' => '#billing-zip',
        'container' => '#billing-container',
    ],
    'options' => ['id' => 'billing-container'],
])->textInput(['maxlength' => 11, 
               'name'=> 'Billing_Address[zip]', 
               'id'=>'billing-zip']); 

//Shipping
$form->field($shipping_address, 'zip', 
[
    'selectors' => [
        'input' => '#shipping-zip',
        'container' => '#shipping-container',
    ],
    'options' => ['id' => 'shipping-container'],
])->textInput(['maxlength' => 11, 
               'name'=> 'Shipping_Address[zip]', 
               'id'=>'shipping-zip']);
```

As you can see we added custom *id* attribute in *textInput* options, and set corresponding selector for js validation in *field* options. [Read about *selectors* property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#$selectors-detail)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the question with the current code. Now the second field (with the code as shown in the question) is working perfectly. The problem is, the first field (with the code unchanged) is not validating anymore. Did I miss something?

Comment: @NthDegree try to specify *id* and *selectors* for each element, for `$billing_addess` model and for `$shipping_address` model too

Comment: hell yes it works! I changed the selectors and id for the other field too now and had an additional small error on the controller with setting a wrong scenario. Thank you!