# Yii2: Submit validation of form with two instances of same model

Tags: php, forms, validation, activerecord, yii2

Follow up to: [Yii2: Validation in form with two instances of same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143793/yii2-validation-in-form-with-two-instances-of-same-model)

I have a model Booking with the fields shipping_address and billing_address, both of the model Address. I now want to print them to the same form which basically works pretty well. The validation works on filling the fields with data, but it fails on submitting the form.

In the controller, the billing address is set with the fields of an existing Address model and the shipping address is set with a new Address model:

```
 public function actionCreate()
{

    $model = new Donation();

    if (!empty($_POST['Address'])) {

        //TODO: Save models

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

    } else {

        $user = User::find(Yii::$app->user->identity->id)->one();
        $billing_address = $user->getBillingAddress()->one();

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'billing_address' => $billing_address,
            'shipping_address' => new Address()
        ]);
    }
}
```

The following code shows how the fields are printed.

Billings-fields:

```
<?= $form->field(
        $billing_address,
        'address_line_1',
        [
            'selectors' => [
                'input' => '#billing-address_line_1',
                'error' => '#billing-address_line_1',
                'container' => '.billing-address_line_1'
            ],
            'options' =>
                ['class' => 'billing-address_line_1']
        ])->textInput([
            'maxlength' => 45,
            'name'=> 'Billing_Address[address_line1]',
            'id'=>'billing-address_line_1',
    ]); ?>
```

Shipping-fields:

```
<?= $form->field(
        $shipping_address,
        'address_line_1',
        [
            'selectors' => [
                'input' => '#shipping-address_line_1',
                'error' => '#shipping-address_line_1',
                'container' => '.shipping-address_line_1'
            ],
            'options' =>
                ['class' => 'shipping-address_line_1']
        ])->textInput([
                'maxlength' => 45,
                'name'=> 'Shipping_Address[address_line1]',
                'id'=>'shipping-address_line_1',
    ]); ?>
```

As the following screenshot shows, the validation works on filling out the form:

[image]

The problem now - it doesn't work when i click the create button:

[image]

Any ideas on how i could solve this? What is the difference between the validation on filling out and the validation on clicking the button?

Comment: Please show the controller code

Comment: I added the controller code, thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the question but as I understand it you would like to save both addresses in the database. right?

Comment: And plase show all the create action of your controller. I see only a part.

Comment: I updated the code, but there's not much more to see actually. When I click the create button, i don't get to the controller again, it fails on ajax validating, there is no request done.

Comment: and yes, @scaisEdge, I want to save both models. The problem is that the validation does not work because when e.g. field address_line is missing in addressmodel2 it also is marked as missing in addressmodel1 on clicking "create".

Answer (score 0):

I would do so, I would not do the creation of the second address directly in rendering function but rather would create the first model and then would pass to the function.

```
 } else {

      $user = User::find(Yii::$app->user->identity->id)->one();
      $billing_address = $user->getBillingAddress()->one();
      $shipping_address = new Address();


      return $this->render('create', [
          'model' => $model,
          'billing_address' => $billing_address,
          'shipping_address' => $shipping_address,
      ]);
  }
```